# error: no matching function for call to 'Stack<int>::Peek()'

Tags: c++

I keep getting the following error: error: no matching function for call to 'Stack::Peek()'

I am new to C++ and I cannot figure out why I am getting the error

This is my Peek() function.

```
int Peek(T data)
{
    if(IsEmpty ())
        return -1;
     else
        return top -> data;

}
```

and this is my main() function.

```
int main()
{
    Stack<int> s1;

    cout << "*declare stack s1\ns1=" << s1 << endl; // stack initially set to 0
    cout << "s1.Size()=" << s1.Size() << endl;
    cout << "s1.IsEmpty()=" << ((s1.IsEmpty()) ? "T" : "F") << endl;
    cout << "s1.IsFull()=" << ((s1.IsFull()) ? "T" : "F") << endl;
    cout << "s1.Peek()=" << s1.Peek() << endl;
    cout << endl;

    Stack<char> s4;

    for (char c='a'; c<='z'; c++)s4.Push(c);
    cout << "s4=" << s4 << endl;
    cout << "s4.Size()=" << s4.Size() << endl;
    cout << "s4.IsEmpty()=" << ((s4.IsEmpty()) ? "T" : "F") << endl;
    cout << "s4.IsFull()=" << ((s4.IsFull()) ? "T" : "F") << endl;
    cout << "s4.Peek()=" << s4.Peek() << endl;
}
```

I get the error whenever the Peek function is called in main so I was wondering if anyone could help me with this.

Comment: Is `Peek` actually a method of `Stack`? It looks like you're just defining an unrelated function.

Comment: Please include more of your code, or even better a minimal example with the same behavior

Answer (score 0):

You defined a Peek method, but not Stack::Peek. Your method should have this signature: `int Stack::Peek(T data)`

Answer (score 0):

Because you are calling it without any argument. Your declaration:

```
int Peek(T data)
```

Your invocation:

```
s4.Peek()
```

Indeed a stack data type doesn't need an argument to the peek function (nor you use it). You should modify your original function to `int Peek()`.

Answer (score 0):

Your function Peak is declared as having one parameter

```
int Peek(T data);
```

However you call it without any argument

```
cout << "s1.Peek()=" << s1.Peek() << endl;
```

So the compiler does not know a function with name Peak that has no parameter.